# How to pass a function as a prop into a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass a function to a custom button component in React. The expected behavior is for "test!" to be printed when you click the button displayed on the screen.

Right now, nothing happens when you click the button.

App.js:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Button } from "./button";

export default function App() {
  function testFunc() {
    console.log("test!");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => testFunc()}></Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

button.js:

```
import React from "react";

export function Button(onClick) {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => onClick}>test</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-browser-pxpo9?file=/src/reactStruggle.js

Disclaimer: I realize this has been asked before. And yet, none of the existing answers I have found work for this case.

Comment: @pilchard hmm. I have tried that before, and trying it now yields an error:


"Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export function Button({onClick}) {
...
... <button onClick={onClick} ....>
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice the OP wasn't destructuring the props correctly. Perhaps explain the problem to make this a more complete answer.